# Unusual high number of exclusive locks in PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, python, postgresql, locking, plpgsql

I am pretty new to database design and PostgreSQL in general, but I am aware of the general concept behind row versioning, transactions and exclusive locks in Postgres (e.g. [this](http://blog.lerner.co.il/in-postgresql-as-in-life-dont-wait-too-long-to-commit/) article gives a pretty good overview).

My current problem is that **a)** I am not sure why I get so many exclusive locks show up in my PG database log files and **b)** why these locks are happening at all.

I run PostgreSQL 10 (+ PostGIS extension) with about 300 Million rows over 5 tables (200GB). I have about 5 scripts (4x PHP and 1x Python Psycopg2) running 24/7 that make a lot of inserts (and `DO UPDATE` with `COALESCE`, in case the entry already exist). However, as far as I understand, PHP Postgres extension commits automatically after each SQL Query and in my Python Script, increasing commits does not significantly reduce locks. I have a couple of triggers that dynamically update rows, but as far as I can tell from the log files they are not the cause of locks. It should generally be very rare that two or more of my scripts insert/update the same row at the same time.

This is an example log entry:

```sql
2018-01-31 01:04:02 CET [808]: [258-1] user=user1,db=maindb,app=[unknown],client=::1 LOG:  process 808 still waiting for ExclusiveLock on page 0 of relation 26889 of database 16387 after 1015.576 ms
2018-01-31 01:04:02 CET [808]: [259-1] user=user1,db=maindb,app=[unknown],client=::1 DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 680. Wait queue: 1728, 152, 808.
2018-01-31 01:04:02 CET [808]: [260-1] user=user1,db=maindb,app=[unknown],client=::1 STATEMENT:  

                INSERT INTO "table1" (...) 
                VALUES (...)                                                                                                                                                                                              
                ON CONFLICT (...)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                DO UPDATE SET                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                ...;
```

I have similar log entries about every 2-3 Minutes. Are they problematic? What do they mean exactly, are the locks finally resolved or is the data of the transaction lost? There is no log entry that states that locks are resolved or updates are finally committed to the database.

The second type of frequent log entry is similar to this:

```sql
2018-01-31 07:22:16 CET [2504]: [16384-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 9999 buffers (3.8%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 7 recycled; write=269.842 s, sync=0.218 s, total=270.123 s; sync files=85, longest=0.054 s, average=0.002 s; distance=66521 kB, estimate=203482 kB
2018-01-31 07:22:46 CET [2504]: [16385-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
```

Does this mean Auto-Vaccum or Auto-Commit that resolves all locks?

**My general question: should I be concerned and do something or simply leave things as they are?**

Comment: That mean process 680 set an exclusive lock. You will habe to check what this process does. It might do extensive work or sometimes there is underlying latency problem in the database (slow I/O for example).

Comment: Thank you Klaus. Could you explain how I can find out what the process 680 does? It doesn't seem to appear in the log (e.g. "680...acquired ExclusiveLock"

Comment: I found [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) page explaining how to monitor locks. It looks like none of my locks exist any longer than a few minutes, which suggests that they are not problematic at all

Comment: Your log line complains about 1 second. So why are minutes OK now?

Comment: Most locks are between 1000 and 100.000 ms, but there seems to be quite some fluctuation. The log line above was just one representative example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I found out what is causing these locks and also how to solve them. All Exclusive locks happened on one relation in the database:
`...ExclusiveLock on page 0 of relation 26889 of database...`

What is 26889?

```sql
SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE OID=26889
```

Result: `idx_post_hashtags`

It was all caused by a GIN index over a particular column with Array (Text). Furthermore, this GIN index was useless, as the array had a variable length and looking up any specific array value did not benefit from the index. I dropped it: all Exclusive Locks gone!

Reading the logs carefully really helps.